# Disable all checkboxes except "checked" react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have listing of products and user can compare upto 4 products, when user checked 4 products I want to disable all checkboxes so user cannot select other product for compare until unless it uncheck one of 4 checkboxes.

```
const [checkedddItems, setCheckedItems] = useState({checkedItems : {}})
const handleComparePackage = (e, packageId) => {
    const { id, checked } = e.target;
    const updatedCheckedItems = comparedPackages.includes(packageId)? { [id]: checked } : {checkedddItems, [id] : checked }
    console.log(updatedCheckedItems);
    setCheckedItems({checkedItems: updatedCheckedItems})
  }
```

```
{ insurancePackages.map((insPackage) => {
              return (
                <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6" key={insPackage.id}>
                  <div className="insurance-card active">
                    {compareSwitch &&
                      <div className="form-check">
                        <input 
                          className="form-check-input" 
                          type="checkbox"
                          id={insPackage.id}
                          checked={checkedddItems[insPackage.id]}
                          disabled={!checkedddItems[insPackage.id]}
                          onChange={(e) => { handleComparePackage(e, insPackage.id) }} />
                      </div>
                    }
                    <div className="thumb">
                      <img src="/insurance/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="title">
                        {insPackage.company.name}
                      </div>
                      <div className="text-detail">
                        {insPackage.description}
                        <br />
                        <Link href="/">
                          <a>View Package Details</a>
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                     </div>
                )
              })
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it seems like you need some way to disable all checkboxes when the following conditions are met:

- the checkbox is not checked,
- the amount of total checked items > 3

This should simply turn into a simple boolean statement in the `disabled` attribute on the checkbox `<input/>`.

```
<input 
  className="form-check-input" 
  type="checkbox"
  id={insPackage.id}
  checked={checkedddItems[insPackage.id]}
  disabled={!checkedddItems[insPackage.id] && checkedddItems.length > 3} // right here
  onChange={(e) => { handleComparePackage(e, insPackage.id) }} />
```